# Javascript - Force specific data type input OR accept only digits in input

Tags: javascript

Just starting out on my coding journey. I have this prompt and I'm trying to force the user to only input numbers. any other characters are not allowed. Any idea how I can do this?

```
var num = prompt("Enter number");
```

I've tried

```
var num=Number(prompt("Enter number"));
```

I've also tried making a loop like this but i know prompt returns a string:

```
while (typeof(num)!=='number'{
        alert("You did not enter a number);
        var num=prompt("Enter number"));}
```

I've also tried:

```
var num= Number(prompt("Enter number"));
while (num===/==NaN){
        alert("You did not enter a number);
        var num=Number(prompt("Enter number"));}
alert("You did enter a number");
```

Entering any non number characters into the Number prompt results in NaN, so I thought that if the answer is NaN every time non-numerical characters are entered, then the loop would trigger, and otherwise it wouldn't but that doesn't seem to be the case for some reason. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I would recommend fixing the syntax errors in the example.

Comment: You can't use `===` to test for `NaN`, use `isNaN()`

Comment: Apart from the syntax errors, what's wrong with the first while loop?

Comment: @evolutionxbox don't mind the syntax errors, its not how i actually wrote it in the editor. The first loop doesn't work prompt() returns a string even if u enter a number.

Comment: You're thinking of a do while loop. As you're comparing the type before the prompt is called, it will always be `undefined`, which means the loop won't run.

Comment: I've tried :
`if (isNaN(num)!=="false"){
 alert("You did not enter a number");
 var num = prompt("Enter number");
}`
That works. It doesn't work if i change it to `isNaN(num)==/==="true"` Any idea why?

Comment: @evolutionxbox there's an initial prompt before the loop, so the type is already defined as NaN before the loop starts if i enter any non-numerical input.

Comment: (@RamyNabil I was referring to the `typeof` check example) --- I would recommend checking `num`'s type _is what you want_, not what you don't want.

Comment: If you're learning how to code then I'd not worry about validating user input just yet. There are a lot more important things to learn. Start with problems that don't require user input. Here are seven problems to get you started. First, define a function which converts Fahrenheit to Celsius. Second, define the [half-or-thrice-plus-one function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) which given a number `n` returns half of `n` if it's even or else returns thrice `n` plus 1 if it's odd.

Comment: Third, given an object like `{ real: 4, imaginary: 2 }`, which represents a complex number, define a function that given two complex numbers `x` and `y` returns their product (i.e. `x` times `y`). Fourth, given that an action is either `"rock"`, `"paper"` or `"scissors"` define a function which given two actions `a1` and `a2`, for player 1 and player 2 respectively, returns 1, -1 or 0 if player 1 wins, loses or draws respectively.

Comment: Fifth, given that a list of numbers is either `null` (i.e. empty list) or something like `{ first: 1, rest: { first: 2, rest: null }}` (i.e. the list containing 1 and 2) where `first` is a number and `rest` is another list of numbers, define a function which given a list of numbers returns the sum of all the numbers. Sixth, define a function which given a list of numbers returns the same list of numbers in reverse order.

Comment: Seventh, define a function which given a natural number `n` returns a list of numbers starting with `n` and ending with 1 such that for each element of the list `x` which is not 1, the next element is `hotpo(x)` where `hotpo` is the half-or-thrice-plus-one function you defined earlier. If `n` is 1 then just return a list with the single element `1`.

Comment: @AaditMShah thank you so so much. I'll definitely get on those! Just gotta familiarise myself some more with the language, first :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var answer = prompt("Enter a number:");
while (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(answer)) {
    alert("You did not enter a number.");
    answer = prompt("Enter a number: ");
}
alert("You entered a number.");
```

### How does this work?

`/^[0-9]+$/` is known as a regular expression. `^` specifies start of the string, `$` specifies the end of the string, `[0-9]` specifies a digits, and `+` specifies `one or more occurrences of`. The given regular expression says "starting from the start of the string up to the end of the string, there should be one or more occurrences of a digit, and nothing else." The `nothing else` part comes in because we are not accepting anything other than digits. If we were, we would put them in the regular expression.

`/^[0-9]+$/.test` returns a boolean depending on whether or not the string matches the given regular expression.

Comment: i actually tried it with regex but i guess i didn't get the syntax right.

Comment: thanks btw. My regex was /\d+/ but i guess that wasnt correct. I thought if it was only checking 1 character that id put in a for loop to go through the chars, but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

Prompts aren't usually the best for inputs since they do not allow any control, but if you're okay with a while loop this might be a good solution:

```
var answer = prompt("Enter number")
while (answer !== parseInt(answer, 10).toString()) {
    alert("Please enter only numbers!");
    answer = prompt("Enter number");
}
```

`parseInt(answer, 10)` "extracts" Numbers from Strings (the second argument is the base, in our case `10` i.e. decimal). `parseInt("5", 10)` is `5`, and `parseInt("5foo", 10)` is also `5`.

Basically, if the user enters an integer into the `prompt`, then `parseInt(answer, 10).toString() === answer` is true. We use `.toString()` to convert the resulting Number to String so we can compare it with the actual value that the user entered, which is always stored as a String in case of `prompt`.

We can use this logic to check if the user *actually* entered an integer or not.

That said, I would really recommend you to use something like `<input type="number">` which would 'enforce' numeric inputs in a much easier/straightforward way.

Comment: Just so you're aware, this solution will consider `5.0` to be an incorrect value, even though it is a valid number. - Consider using `parseFloat`?

Comment: thanks for the contribution. In your example of "5foo" the user still entered non-numerical characters that got stored as a string, even if the numbers were extracted. What I'm looking for is something that gives an error if even a single non-numerical character is detected.

Comment: I'm aware, OP only wants "numeric characters" and `.` is a non-numeric character :)

Comment: @RamyNabil did you try the code? The prompt will appear again if the user enters `5foo`. We're using the fact that `parseInt` extracts only numbers and then comparing it with the actual answer -- if the result from `parseInt` and actual answer is the same, then the user did enter only numbers.

Comment: @NamanyayG I get it now. Gonna test it and let you know. Took a minute to understand. These are all really new concepts to me :) It's like checking whether Math.floor(Math.Sqrt(x))==Math.Sqrt(x) to check if a number is a perfect square.

Comment: @RamyNabil yes exactly -- it's a neat 'trick'! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @evolutionxbox btw i replaced parseInt with parseFloat and entered 2 & 2.5 but it keeps triggering the loop for some reason. NVM figured it out. was coz i was still using Number() in the prompt.

Comment: You might want to edit your question. Live debugging in comments is not useful.

Comment: sorry. im still very new to all this. :) Ill post an answer that incorporates all your answers.

Answer (score -1):

So, on top of the regex solution posted, here's a summation of both @namanyayG's, Barmar's and @evolutionxbox's answers:

```
var num = Number(prompt("Enter whole number"));

while (num !== parseInt(num).toString()) {
    alert("Please enter only numbers!");
    num = prompt("Enter number");
}
```

OR for Float numbers:

```
var num = prompt("Enter whole number");

while (num !== parseFloat(num).toString()) {
    alert("Please enter only numbers!");
    num = prompt("Enter number");
}
```

OR

```
var num = Number(prompt("Enter whole number"));

while (isNaN(num)!=="false"){
    alert("You did not enter a whole number");
    var num = prompt("Enter number");
}
```

For some unknown to me reason, `isNaN(num)!=="false"` is not the same as `isNaN(num)==/==="true"`

Comment: There is no symbol like "==/===". Also, you need to unquote `false` in answer #3.